# Big O notation: O((n-1)!) or O(n!) for T((n-1)!)?

Tags: big-o, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I have an algorithm that I have analysed to have a time complexity of `(n-1)!`.

To put this in big-O notation, would I write `O((n-1)!)` or `O(n!)`?

Answer (score 3):

Let's have a look:

```
limn → ∞ n!/(n-1)! = limn → ∞ n = ∞
```

Thus (see the [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Related_asymptotic_notations)) `(n-1)!` is in `o(n!)` (little-o).

So if your algorithm complexity is in `O((n-1)!)`, it is also in `O(n!)`, so it is not wrong to write `O(n!)` instead of `O((n-1)!)`, but `O((n-1)!)` is a tighter bound, so you should use this one.

It is basically the same as writing `π ≤ 22/7` or `π ≤ 4`. Both is right, but `π ≤ 22/7` is closer.

Comment: So would it also be "not wrong" to describe a `O(n)` allgorithm as `O(n^2)`?

Comment: @StephenC Since Big-O is an upper bound, an bigger upper bound is never wrong. But normaly you are looking for the tightest bound you can show, so if you can show O(n) you don't want to say it is in O(n²). In the case of n! the difference is not that big. (n-1)! is already exponential, so an other linear factor is not that bad. I know that some professors wrote a slightly worse complexity in their articles, just because it is more readable.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `O((n-1)!)`.

`O(n!)` is actually `O(n⋅(n-1)!)`